# building custom data generator

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, imagedatagenerator

I want to build a multi output model.
That's why I need a custom data generator.

My data looks below:

```
image_path | y1 | y2 | y3 |
```

My data generator looks below:

```
class AydFashionDataGenerator(): 
    
    def __init__(self, Xy_train: pd.DataFrame, Xy_test: pd.DataFrame, shape=(224, 224)) -> None: 
        self.Xy_train = Xy_train 
        self.Xy_test = Xy_test 
        self.shape = shape 
        
        merged = pd.concat([Xy_train, Xy_test], axis=0) 
        self.yakaTipi_arr_max = merged["YakaTipi_id"].value_counts().index.max()
        self.CepOzelligi_arr_max = merged["CepOzelligi_id"].value_counts().index.max()
        self.KolBoyuAciklama_arr_max = merged["KolBoyuAciklama_id"].value_counts().index.max()


    
    def generate_split_indexes(self):  
         pass 

    def cast_id_2_one_hot(self, arr: np.array, ds_max: int): 
        zeros = np.zeros((arr.size, ds_max + 1)) 
        zeros[np.arange(arr.size), arr] = 1
        return zeros
    
    def preprocess_image(self, img_path):
        """
            Used to perform some minor preprocessing on the image before inputting into the network.
        """  
        img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
        img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
        img = tf.image.resize(img, [224, 224])
        return img.numpy() 
    
    def generate_images(self, is_training: bool, bathc_size=16): 
        """
            Used to generate a batch with images when training/testing/validating our Keras model.  
        """
        # arrays to store our batched data 
        images, attr_yaka, attr_kolBoyu, attr_cep = [], [], [], [] 
        
        if is_training:
            Xy = self.Xy_train 
        else:
            Xy = self.Xy_test 

        while True:
            for idx, row in Xy.iterrows():
                im = self.preprocess_image(row["paths"]) 
                id_yaka = row["YakaTipi_id"]
                id_cep = row["CepOzelligi_id"]
                id_kolBoyu = row["KolBoyuAciklama_id"] 

                images.append(im) 
                attr_yaka.append(id_yaka) 
                attr_cep.append(id_cep) 
                attr_kolBoyu.append(id_kolBoyu) 

                if len(images) >= bathc_size:
                    yield np.array(images),  {"YakaTipi": self.cast_id_2_one_hot(np.array(attr_yaka), self.yakaTipi_arr_max), 
                                             "CepOzelligi": self.cast_id_2_one_hot(np.array(attr_cep), self.CepOzelligi_arr_max), 
                                             "KolBoyuAciklama": np.array(attr_kolBoyu)
                                             }
                    images, attr_yaka, attr_kolBoyu, attr_cep = [], [], [], [] 

            if not is_training:
                break
```

When I call the fit function of my moodel, after one training epoch, the test generator works and show the results of vall loss and vall metrics.
After that, I see the warning below:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 34.0 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
```

For coming epochs, I don't see the validaton results.
How to tackle with that problem ?